# TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for gulpfile.ts

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, ts-node, yarnpkg-v2

I get the error running `yarn run package`. Adding `NODE_OPTIONS="--loader ts-node/esm"` didn't help.

I have seen https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1062 but I tried different `target`s and that didn't help.

`package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:production": "npm run prestart && npm prune --production",
    "watch": "tsc --w",
    "prestart": "npm run build && func extensions install",
    "start:host": "func start",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel start:host watch",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\"",
    "package": "gulp build && gulp package"
  },
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^1.0.1-beta1",
    "@types/gulp": "^4.0.9",
    "@types/gulp-zip": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.13",
    "del": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "gulp-zip": "^5.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "azure-devops-node-api": "^11.2.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "decode-uri-component": "0.2.2",
    "glob-parent": "6.0.2",
    "qs": "6.10.3",
    "string_decoder": "1.3.0"
  }
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strict": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./gulpfile.ts"
  ],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

`node` 18.12.1, `npm` 9.1.3, and `yarn` 3.3.0.